# Python units module for conversion between liters and milliliters not working

Tags: python, data-conversion

Using the 'units module for performing basic conversions between units.
However it does not seem to be possible to perform an easy conversion between liters and milliliters...why?

```
>>> from units import unit

>>> one_liter = unit('L')(1)   
>>> one_liter
Quantity(1, LeafUnit('L', False))

>>> unit('mL')(one_liter)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/heinz/src/units/lib/python2.6/site-packages/units/abstract.py", line 23, in __call__
    raise IncompatibleUnitsError()
units.exception.IncompatibleUnitsError
```

Comment: Conventionally, lowercase l is used for liter, although I imagine the SI multiplier prefixes should work with any unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `define_units()` in the `predefined` sub-module to use this package.

```
import units
import units.predefined

units.predefined.define_units()
one_liter = unit('L')(1)
unit('mL')(one_liter)
```

I think this package could have been better designed -- as you've discovered, it's easy to accidentally use user-defined units rather than standard ones.